# Merlin combustion chamber pressure

Tags: spacex, engine-design, merlin-1d, pressure

What is the combustion chamber pressure for Merlin?

I mean the average and the maximum

The Raptor engine was tested with a maximum 330 bar. I would like to compare them

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Merlin), the operating pressure is 9.7MPa or about 100 bar for the Merlin 1D. I don't know what the maximum pressure would be.